# copy data from one spanner db to an existing spanner db

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I need to find a tool or a technique that will generate insert statements from a spanner db so I can insert them into another spanner db.  I need to selectively choose which insert statements or rows to migrate so the spanner export/import tool will not work.  The destination db will already exist and it will have existing data in it.  The amount of data is small - roughly 15 tables with 10 to 20 rows in each table.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Cloud Spanner Dataflow Connector](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector) to write your pipeline/data loader to move data in and out of Spanner. You can use a custom SQL query with the Dataflow reader to read the subset of data that you want to export.

Depending on how wide your tables are, if you are dealing with a relatively small amount of data, a simpler way to this could be using the `gcloud spanner databases execute-sql` command-line utility. For each of your tables, you could use the utility to run a SQL query to get the rows you want to export from the table and write the result to a file in the csv format using the `--format=csv` argument. Then you could write a small wrapper around Cloud Spanner Insert APIs to read the data from the CSV files and send insert mutations to the target database.

Comment: can we copy from one project to another?